# Going back starts from page 1

Tags: magento-1.9

When i am browsing my store and for example on page 3, I go into a product and the press the back button - this then takes me back to page 1 not back to where i was on page 3.

How do i sort this?

Comment: do you use some kind of ajax paging?

Comment: I have no idea?

Comment: Does your address bar get updated with a new URL for each page?

Comment: No stays exactly the same